# How to read in xls table into R

Tags: r, excel, xls

I have a xls table in Excel that looks like following:

```
Bolagets firma              Redogörelse - Liv       
Samtliga bolag                      

Org nr      -               1996

Balansräkning. Belopp i kkr.                        Sida 1 (19)

1                                               2   3
Assets

A.  Tecknat ej inbetalt kapital                 0   0

B.  Immateriella tillgångar                 
    1   Goodwill                                0   
    2   Andra immateriella tillgångar       36 651  36 651

C.  Placeringstillgångar                778 288 001 778 288 001

D.  Placeringstillgångar för vilka livförsäkrings-              30 921 242  30 921 242
    tagaren bär placeringsrisken                    

E.  Återförsäkrares andel av                    
    försäkringstekniska avsättningar                    
    1   Avsättning för ej intjänade premier         579 
        och kvardröjande risker             
    2   Livförsäkringsavsättning                    1 369 453   
    3   Avsättning för oreglerade skador            534 971 
    4   Avsättning för återbäring och rabatter          0   
    5   Övriga försäkringstekniska avsättningar         581 
    6   Avsättning för livförsäkringar för vilka            0      1 905 584
        försäkringstagaren bär placeringsrisken             

F.  Fordringar                  
    1   Fordringar avseende direkt försäkring                   5 804 718   
    2   Fordringar avseende återförsäkring                     94 319   
    3   Övriga fordringar                        7 715 106  13 614 143

G.  Andra tillgångar                    
    1   Materiella tillgångar och varulager         184 140 
    2   Kassa och bank                                           5 877 691  
    3   Egna aktier                                          93 264 
    4   Övriga tillgångar           129 360 6 284 455

H.  Förutbetalda kostnader och                  
    upplupna intäkter                   
    1   Upplupna ränte- och hyresintäkter           16 978 205  
    2   Förutbetalda anskaffningskostnader          2 502 074   
    3   Övriga förutbetalda kostnader och           710 516 20 190 795
        upplupna intäkter               

SUMMA TILLGÅNGAR                        851 240 871
```

Is it possible to read in it into R? Right now I get a lot of warnings when I try `read.table` family or `read.xls`. I am sorry that the numbers jumped below. Esentially the table has 3 columns below "Assets" in the table above.

Best Regards!

Comment: Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader is one of them

Answer (score 0):

According to your warning, it appears that your column headings do not match your number of columns.  This makes sense since your xls file isn't set up as a table. `read.table()` is expecting that every line in the file will be identical in format.

Row A has 4 columns: "A", "Tecknat ej inbetalt kapital", "0", "0"
Row B has 2 columns: "B", "Immateriella tillgångar"
Row B.1 has 3 columns: "1", "Goodwill", "0"
Row B.2 has 7 columns: "2", "Andra immateriella tillgångar", "36", "651",  "36", "651"
etc.

What you need is to move your section headings (e.g. "Immateriella tillgångar" or "B") into columns. These columns will be factors once you start using the data in R.